# Is it permissible to become a private investigator and a spy?

Tags: sharia, profession

Is it permissible for a Muslim to be a private investigator?

Like it's your job to spy on people.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the agency you're serving. If the agency is truly working in the best interests of the Muslim community and the people in general then you're serving a noble cause.

PS: Off course, you and the agency must observe Islamic laws in your investigations. That would need the cases be authorized by a pious, scholarly Muslim judge. But apparently outside the Islamic Republic of Iran (which has an Islamic judicial system and investigative body) such conditions don't exist at all.